# Как сократить код

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, помогите пожалуйста сократить данную запись:

```
if(i == 0 || i ==  10 || i == 20 || i == 30|| i == 40)
```

Так, чтобы последующие 50, 60, 70 и.т.д не приходилось прописывать в условие.

Comment: Если кратно 10-ти, то `if(i % 10 === 0)`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло!

Answer (score 2):

Если кратно 10-ти, то `if(i % 10 === 0)`.

Comment: Здесь уместен оператор `===`? Результатом операции `%` может быть или `number` или `NaN`

Comment: У автора только числа. Ответственность за слабую типизацию в JS я не несу.